# adding static library to iOS

Tags: flutter, ffi, dart-ffi

I want to add a static library to iOS.

first of all, I added `some_library.a` file to `ios/lib` directory, then I add `vendored_libraries` to `.podspec` file like this:

```
  ...
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
  s.ios.vendored_libraries = 'lib/some_library.a'
end
```

but I get this error:

```
Xcode build done.                                            7.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: library not found for -lsome_library
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?